# Neural Networks: why do we need an activation function?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I tried to run a simple neural network without any activation function, and the network does not converge. I'm using MSE cost function for MNIST classification.

However, if I apply Rectified Linear activation function to the hidden layer (output = max(0, x), where x is the weighted sum), then it converges fine.

Why eliminating negative outputs from previous layer helps with learning?

Comment: How do you measure convergence? Is the objective function decreasing?

Comment: I count the number of mis-classified digits.

Answer (score 6):

## Linearity vs non-linearity

A basic perceptron is merely a weighted  linear combination of its input signals. A layer of perceptrons is still a linear regressor/classifier. The network will only be able to solve nonlinear problems if we make the function approximator (the neural network) nonlinear itself. This can be done by applying nonlinear activation functions on the output signals of the layers such as the ReLU function.

### Rectified Linear Unit

[image: The ReLU function]

How come the ReLU is a nonlinear activation function, when the output signal is just `max(0, y)`? The answer lies in cancelling out the negative values (replacing them with 0). Since you can't describe the ReLU function curve with a straight line, the ReLU is not a linear activation function.

[image: The ReLU curve]

Comment: The question is, *why* cancelling out the negative values helps with learning?

Comment: Because you make the function approximator (the network) nonlinear, which is required to correctly classify the MNIST dataset

Comment: Are you saying that any non-linearity will work for MNIST?

Comment: Yes, any nonlinear activation function will work. However, some nonlinear functions are a better fit for the MNIST classification task - such as the ReLU.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is simple. You need to add some sort of nonlinearity to your neural network, otherwise you will end up with solving a simple linear equation.

Assume you have an input vector x and two hidden layers represented by weight matrices W1 and W2. Without any activation function, your neural network is going to output y = x W1 W2 which is equal to y = x W  such that W=W1 W2. This is nothing but a matrix multiplication.

If you use activation functions such as ReLU or Sigmoid etc. you'll get a nice non-linear function which is capable of fitting to some interesting data.

Comment: It seems to me, that ReLU still does the simple y = x*W, with negative values cancelled out. I'd like to know why removing those neg values help?

Comment: I've been wondering the same exact thing.  Whenever I hear "because you need it to be non-linear" I just hear "because it's got electrolytes".  It still doesn't explain why.